# Java convert byte[] to BigInteger

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, biginteger, uint8array

In Java, I can get a `BigInteger` from a `String` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "banana";
    byte[] bytes = input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(bytes);
    System.out.println("bytes:      " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
    System.out.println("bigInteger: " + bigInteger);
}
```

Which will print

```
bytes:      [98, 97, 110, 97, 110, 97]
bigInteger: 108170603228769
```

I'm trying to get the same result in JavaScript using the [big-integer library](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/). But as you can see this code returns a different value:

```
var bigInt = require('big-integer');

function s(x) {
    return x.charCodeAt(0);
}

var bytes = "banana".split('').map(s);
var bigInteger = bigInt.fromArray(bytes);
console.log("bytes:      " + bytes);
console.log("bigInteger: " + bigInteger);
```

output:

```
bytes:      98,97,110,97,110,97
bigInteger: 10890897
```

Is there a way to get the result I'm getting in Java with JavaScript?
And would that be possible also if the array has a length of 32?

Comment: @rottenoats big-integer *is* a Javascript library. This *is* a Javascript question.

Comment: Can you explain how `[98, 97, 110, 97, 110, 97]` gets transformed to `108170603228769`? I'm afraid I don't see the pattern. A more minimal example, like an array with two or three elements, might be informative

Comment: The doc page you linked says `fromArray` defaults base to 10. Given this byte array has the top bit of the first byte clear, [the Java BigInteger ctor is using effectively base 256 bigendian](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-byte:A-) **Use base 256.**

Comment: @CertainPerformance: try a hex output for the bytes and for the BigInteger. Then you will see where the individual bytes go. Hex output will need exactly two hex digits per byte.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: The bytes are, in hex: `[62,61,6E,61,6E,61]`. The hex reprentation of the BigInteger with value `108170603228769` is `62616E616E61`. I guess it is clear now how these values get transformed to the BigInteger. It is not obvious from the decimal representations, but in hex it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BigInteger(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)) takes the two's-complement binary representation while [`bigInt.fromArray()`](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/#fromarraydigits-base--10-isnegative) takes an array of digits with a default base of 10.

As dave_thompson_085 said, you can use base 256:

```
var bigInteger = bigInt.fromArray(bytes, 256);
console.log("bigInteger: " + bigInteger); // 108170603228769
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when running this:
     `/Users/sietzevliegen/node_modules/big-integer/BigInteger.js:1122`
     `val = val.add(digits[i].times(pow));`
     `TypeError: digits[i].times is not a function`

Comment: It works with `http://peterolson.github.com/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js`, not sure why it fails for you.

Comment: It works actually. The variable I was passing was incorrect, that's how I messed it up. Using the snippet from the original question solved that problem